# How can I sort data into 3 alphabetical subgroups with SQL?

Tags: sql, select, alphabetical

I'm displaying student data for teachers at my school using SQL, and for usability reasons it needs to be displayed with very unique sorting, with 3 subsets of the alphabet dividing the dataset, then normal sorting within that.

It should spit out something like this:

Last names A-F, sorted by period, then by last name

Last names G-O, sorted by period, then by last name

Last names P-Z, sorted by period, then by last name

It's currently sorted by period and last name fairly simply, and I can use three different queries to split the data as such, but I don't know how to do it all in one.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Student ORDER BY per, last;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a conditional expression in the `order by`?

```
order by (case when last < 'G' then 1
               when last < 'P' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         per, last
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEFT(UPPER(last), 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'F' THEN 1
    WHEN LEFT(UPPER(last), 1) BETWEEN 'G' AND 'O' THEN 2
    WHEN LEFT(UPPER(last), 1) BETWEEN 'P' AND 'Z' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END AS LETTER_GROUP,
  per,
  last
FROM
  Student
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really break the result set up into groups/partitions. You can *group* the results set with a `group by` clause, but that summarizes down to a single row per group. There's also `over/partition by`, but that's more analytic. You'll want to do something like this:

```
select group_1 = case
                   when upper(substring(t.surname,1,1)) between 'A' and 'F' then '1:A-F'
                   when upper(substring(t.surname,1,1)) between 'G' and 'O' then '2:G-O'
                   when upper(substring(t.surname,1,1)) between 'P' and 'Z' then '3:P-Z'
                   else                                                        '4:Other'
                 end,
       *     
from my_table t    -- SORT SEQUENCE:
order by 1,        -- 1. Ordinal Column 1 (grouping by letter of last name)
         t.period, -- 2. Period
         t.surname -- 3. Surname
```

You don't say what flavor of SQL you're using. Depending on what dialect your DBMS speaks, you have to restate the 1st column

```
group_1 = case ... end
```

to be

```
case ... end as group_1
```